# How to change UI display / change code from home assistant

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, virtualbox, home-assistant

[image]

How to change UI display / change code from home assistant ? maybe someone has used it?
can it be installed vs code in the home assistant?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install vs code in home assistant, go to settings -> addon-> addon store. search for vs code.

if it isn't there, click the three dots and add

https://github.com/hassio-addons/repository

to the repository list.
go back and search for vs code and install it. enable show in sidebar.
I hope this solves your problem